# I'm new to blender, Help me!

Tags: modeling, gpu

I want to learn Blender, Unity and Unreal, and I’m about to purchase new laptop.
The question is do I need touch screen or touch tablet for blender?
Do I need to be artist to use Blender?
Also, did I need high end gpu like (gtx 1070,1060)?
Thank you

Comment: You don't have to buy touch screen or tablet, you can modeling with just keyboard and mouse. But if you want to do something like texture painting or sculpting, you might be needed(but not necessary).

Comment: You don't need artistic skills, they could help, but you can develop that with the time, just practice. High end gpus can speed some kind of job, but a very good cpu is preferred imho. Next versions of blender will need a quite recent video card though (opengl 3.3+ iirc): look for modern gpus anyway.

Comment: If you just want to learn you don't have to have the best laptop in the world, just a basic one, with a good tablet like wacom. Then in several years when you'll know enough you'll find the need to buy a better machine. At the beginning, to learn the basics, you don't need to create objects with millions of faces and hig-res textures

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I’ve been using Blender for a long time now and I’ve always been working on a MacBookPro Mid 2014. Depending on what you do, you will have to know what graphics card you use. I wouldn’t suggest you using NVIDIA because they have graphic cards specialized for gaming and not 3D rendering and video editing.

If you are doing basic modeling you don’t have know art and all that stuff. If you are aiming to do sculpting and texture painting it’s basically essential. I hope that concludes everything

Comment: ...You mean gaming like all that filled of 3d rendering, right? :-)

Comment: mmmmm... I also work on a Macbook pro and I don't think it's the best to work on Blender, on the contrary everyone recommend NVIDIA card to work on Blender

Comment: Of course now I have switched to the new iMac running with an AMG Graphics Card and everything is working out perfectly.

Comment: that interests me, is it the card inside the imac by default? is there a review about its performance vs NVIDIA's?

Comment: The Card is in there by default and I’ve noticed Computers with a NVIDIA Card have a lot better gaming performance than my iMac.

Comment: Yes but I'm interested in Blender only, not gaming, is the imac card as good as the INVIDIA? Actually I'd like to switch to Linux but if Apple can make a good machine for Blender, why not...

Comment: My brother uses a NVIDIA Card and I’ve compared those two and I have noticed the AMD Radeon Pro in my iMac was a bite faster than his Lenovo Game Cube with a NVIDIA 1070

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try to get more informations on this topic to make my mind up   ;)

Comment: Yh so will I :D

Comment: Radeon Pro 580 has 5.5GFLOPS of compute performance, GTX1070 has 6.5. On top of that Apple’s OpenCL implementation is horrible. Apple machine makes sense only if you need to code for OSX or iOS or you need to use Final Cut Pro. Any Apple stuff gets destroyed by custom machine on Linux for the same money. For modeling you have to know art stuff, you are creating shapes in 3d instead of creating it in 2d, it's the only difference. And you need to know the same fundamentals doesn't matter if you move vertices by mouse or draw strokes with tablet.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you very much. I actually didn’t know that ;D